# How to break "while" loop in Java when condition is stacked

Tags: java

I have following Java code:

```
while( someMethod() )   {

   //do something
}
```

someMethod() parses some text with regex. when the file is too big, it can take too much time, and I prefer to break it.
How could I set timeout and break the loop if someMethod() runs out the time?

Thank you!

P.S. important: someMethod() is not my code, I cannot change it

Comment: `someMethod()` has to return a boolean. You have to control what it returns somehow. Without more details, not much we can do.

Comment: it does return boolean, but when it is stacked, it does not return anything.

Comment: What do you mean by “stacked”? That’s not conventional terminology.

Comment: sorry for my English, I meant "stucked" :)

Comment: Can you get to the most inner method that is stuck? perhaps it has timeout?

Comment: the inner method parses some text with regex. when the file is too big, it can take too much time, and I prefer to break it.

Comment: what the someMethod() will return boolean or int or string or object?

Answer (score 3):

You would have to involve a separate thread for the call.

```
final ExecutorService executor = ...;
final Callable<Boolean> someMethodCall = new Callable<>() {
    @Override public boolean call() { return someMethod(); }
};

while (executor.submit(someMethodCall).get(tmoutMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
{
    // whatever
}
```

This will block for the maximum period specified and throw a `TimeoutException` oherwise, which will break out of the loop. You can catch the exception.

Note that this isn't really elegant because the call to the method will remain stuck and usurp that thread possibly forever. There is no safe way around this if the method isn't interruptible.

Answer (score 1):

The complete application including imports:

```
package javaapplication4;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class JavaApplication4 {

    private static final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    private static boolean someMethod(long i) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(i*1000);
        return true;
    }

    private static boolean someMethodTimeOut(long timeOut, final long i) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
        Future<Boolean> res = pool.submit(new Callable<Boolean> (){
            @Override
            public Boolean call() throws Exception {
                return someMethod(i);
            }
        });

        return res.get(timeOut, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final long timeout = 5000;
        long i = 0;

        try {
            while(someMethodTimeOut(timeout, i++)) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            pool.shutdownNow();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement someMethod so that it returns false when it reaches a specified limit:

```
boolean someMethod() {
    long endTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000;
    while (true) {
        // your code logic, you should also set yourChosenTimeoutInMillis here.

        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > yourChosenTimeoutInMillis) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

With this, your while will exit if someMethod falls into an infinite loop in it's core logic.

Comment: nice, but someMethod() is not my code, I cannot change it...

Comment: If that's the case, you should resort to threading, which I could see the others are already suggesting. On a single-threaded run, you cannot proceed until someMethod completes. There's no escape from that.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to create a new thread that calls the method, and then call Thread.join(long timeout) in your main thread.

```
 public class ParserThread extends Thread
    {

    private volatile success = false

    @Override
    public void run()
    { 
        success = someMethod();
    }

    @Override
    public void interrupt()
    {
        // TODO: try to cancel your logic here if possible to avoid wasted CPU cycles.
    }

    public boolean isSuccess()
    {
        return this.success;
    }
}
```

In your main class:

```
ParserThread t = new ParserThread();
t.start();

t.join(5000); // Wait a maximum for 5 second for example

if(t.isSuccess())
{
    // Do something if success
}
else
{
    // Do something else if failure
}
```

Comment: Extending `Thread`---bad idea. Overriding `interrupt`---even worse.